# Problem with running json-prolog:prolog to query an owl file

Tags: ros, json-prolog, knowrob, roslisp, cram

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a cram project running with Ros. i simply want to query an owl file and receive results in cram.

Knowrob is installed on my system and i can run  rosrun rosprolog rosprolog knowrob_common examples.

---

Based on limited documentations and available codes, to query the owl file, i came up with the following code

`(json-prolog:prolog '("rdf_has" ?owlname "http://knowrob.org/kb/srdl2-comp.owl#urdfName"("literal")))`

i received

`; Evaluation aborted on #<SB-KERNEL:CASE-FAILURE expected-type: (OR STRING ROSLISP::URI) datum: NIL>.`

i tried every permutation to place owl address, variable and owl command. same error showed up in all cases.

Moreover, by running `(json-prolog:check-connection)` i have the following error

`[(JSON-PROLOG) WARN] 1504631904.665: Node is not running.`

I am not sure which node i should run and is it neccessary in order to query the owl file?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270436/problem-with-running-json-prolog:prolog-to-query-an-owl-file/) by [aAsoodeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31814/aasoodeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Well, as your warning message suggests, your ROS node is not running. Without a ROS node you cannot do any ROS communication with other nodes. Simply start a new node:

```
(roslisp:start-ros-node "my_awesome_node")
```

and try the query again.

I have a suspicion, though, that the `("literal")` clause will create problems. For beginners I usually suggest to use the `json-prolog:prolog-simple` query, which simply accepts a string instead of a list with the query and parameters as `json-prolog:prolog` does. E.g.:

```
(json-prolog:prolog-simple "rdf_has(OWLNAME, 'http://knowrob.org/kb/srdl2-comp.owl#urdfName', OTHERVAR).")
```

Edit: in case you're interested to know what the correct version of your original query is, this is how I would write it:

```
(json-prolog:prolog '("rdf_has" ?owlname "http://knowrob.org/kb/srdl2-comp.owl#urdfName" ("literal" ?var)))
```

---

Originally posted by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) with karma: 311 on 2017-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2